# Unable to launch a website using KestrelHttpServer (Error : Object reference not set to an instance of an object)

Tags: mono, asp.net-core, centos7

I have installed mono 3.10.0 from source in my Linux VM (Centos 7)

I have installed KVM using the link provided in `ASP.NET` home on `Github`

```
curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aspnet/Home/master/kvminstall.sh | sh && source ~/.kre/kvm/kvm.sh
```

and `kpm restore` is working file and restoring all packages

but i am not able to run  `k kestrel` in the `HelloMvc` samples from [Asp.Net Home Github](https://github.com/aspnet/home)
I gives error

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
  at Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel.Networking.Libuv.loop_size () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel.Networking.UvLoopHandle.Init (Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel.Networking.Libuv uv) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel.KestrelThread.ThreadStart (System.Object parameter) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

I have also tried to isntall `libuv` from source still no luck

## Edit

**Steps Followed for libuv install** :

```
wget http://dist.libuv.org/dist/v1.0.0-rc1/libuv-v1.0.0-rc2.tar.gz
tar -xvf libuv-v1.0.0-rc2.tar.gz
cd libuv-v1.0.0-rc2/
./gyp_uv.py -f make -Duv_library=shared_library
make -C out
sudo cp out/Debug/lib.target/libuv.so /usr/lib/libuv.so.1.0.0-rc2
sudo ln -s libuv.so.1.0.0-rc2 /usr/lib/libuv.so.1
```

## Exception after installing `Libuv` again

```
System.ArgumentException: An element with the same key already exists in the dictionary.
  at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[TKey,TValue].Add (System.Collections.Generic.TKey key, System.Collections.Generic.TValue value) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[DictionaryEntry,String,String] (IEnumerable`1 source, System.Func`2 keySelector, System.Func`2 elementSelector, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel.EnvironmentVariablesConfigurationSource.Load (IDictionary envVariables) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel.EnvironmentVariablesConfigurationSource.Load () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel.Configuration.Add (IConfigurationSource configurationSource) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel.ConfigurationExtensions.AddEnvironmentVariables (IConfigurationSourceContainer configuration) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Comment: This is definitely a libuv error. Can you list the steps you took to compile and symlink libuv locally ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at http://olivierlefebvre.tumblr.com/post/101523386694/asp-vnext-alpa4-on-ubuntu

I fixed like that.

## Step Used

```
git clone https://github.com/joyent/libuv.git
cd libuv
sh autogen.sh
./configure
make
make check
sudo make install
```

Final by adding a symlink to the lib

```
ln /usr/local/lib/libuv.so -sf ~/.kpm/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel/1.0.0-alpha4/native/darwin/universal/libuv.dylib
```

Comment: I tried your method for Libuv and not the exception message is changed... See question for updated info

Comment: The exception you have after re installing libuv comes because you have  doublon in your environment variable, list your env vars and delete doublon. It's not case sensitive

Comment: could you elaborate on the `doublon`... Does it mean environment variables in CAPS and SMALL both...

Comment: yes, it's not case sensitive, so if you have a var name for exemple HTTP_PROXY and http_proxy, it's consider as the same var. take a look at [source code on github](https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel/Sources/EnvironmentVariablesConfigurationSource.cs)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at http://carolynvanslyck.com/blog/2014/09/dotnet-vnext-impressions/ the section on Kestrel.

```
wget http://dist.libuv.org/dist/v1.0.0-rc2/libuv-v1.0.0-rc2.tar.gz
tar -xvf libuv-v1.0.0-rc2.tar.gz
cd libuv-v1.0.0-rc2/
./gyp_uv.py -f make -Duv_library=shared_library
make -C out
sudo cp out/Debug/lib.target/libuv.so /usr/lib/libuv.so.1.0.0-rc2
sudo ln -s libuv.so.1.0.0-rc2 /usr/lib/libuv.so.1
```

This worked for me

Comment: I tried your method for Libuv and not the exception message is changed... See question for updated info

Answer (score 1):

You got an exception because you have two variables with the same name but in the different case. Dump all environment variables before start:

```
printenv > env.dump
```

find duplicated variables and before start unset one of them (save the original value before to restore it after)

Here is [script init.d with example](http://druss.co/2015/06/run-kestrel-in-the-background/)

Just save and unset variable:

```
TMP_SAVE_runlevel_VAR=$runlevel
unset runlevel
```

And the restore it:

```
export runlevel=$TMP_SAVE_runlevel_VAR
```